# Changing language after installation in Visual Studio 2017 for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-mac

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2017 on my Mac but I want to change the language. How can I do that? I cannot find an option in the VS settings to change the language.

Comment: try to install language pack

Comment: Where can I find the language packs?

Comment: I just needed to change the language of my macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio for Mac you can change the lanugage in Preferences - Environment - Visual Style - User Interface Language.

[image]